# Handling Bank Reconciliation with php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am handling bank reconciliation with mysql and php,
I have  two banks from which interest and charges are recorded
Below displays the tables

```
Banks table
| BankID    |   BankName    |
|  01       |       AB Bank |
|  02       |       CD Bank |
```

They user is free to add more banks to the `Banks table`

Below is the reconciliation table, this table receives various values from the bank per a month or two

```
reconcilation table
|   BankID  |   interest    |   Charges     |   Date        | Year  |
|     01    |       20.00   |       10.00   |   2013-05-30  | 2013  |
|     02    |       0.00    |       0.00    |   2013-05-31  | 2013  |
|     01    |       0.20    |       0.00    |   2013-08-27  | 2013  |
|     02    |       50.00   |       0.00    |   2013-08-30  | 2013  |
```

I want to be able to show  the first reconciliation ( that is reconciliation with `2013-05-30` and `2013-05-31` as their date) for the two banks on one table and also show the second reconciliation ( that is reconciliation with `2013-08-30` and `2013-08-27` as their date) for the two banks on different table using one query on the same page. The `reconcilation table` is most often updated every two or three months within a year.

This is tabulated below. For example on one php page we show

```
  ANALYSIS OF BANK ACCOUNTS (2013/05/01 to 2013/05/31)

| Date      |   Details     |   AB Bank     |   CD Bank |
|2013/05/01 |   Interest    |   20.00       |   0.00    |
|           |   Charges     |   10.00       |   0.00    |




 ANALYSIS OF BANK ACCOUNTS (2013/06/01 to 2013/09/31)

| Date      |   Details     |   AB Bank     |   CD Bank |
|2013-06-01 |   Interest    |   0.20        |   50.00   |
|           |   Charges     |   0.00        |   0.00    |
```

NB: The user can add more banks into the `Banks table` which will affect the `reconciliation table` values .

**UPDATE**

This is what I have tried so far

```
/**
 * This queries the various components for the various
 * banks within a particular period
 */ 
$bankAccount1= "SELECT
                    a.bankID,
                    a.interest,
                    a.charges,
                    a.date
                FROM 
                    `Bank Reconciliation` a 
                    group by bankID";

$bankResult1=$db->query($bankAccount1);

while($bankRow1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($bankResult1)){
    $bankID=$bankRow1['bankID'];
    $interest=$bankRow1['interest'];
    $tableHead .='<th>'.$bankID.'</th>';
    $bankInterest .='<td>'.$interest.'</td>';
    $bankCharges .='<td>'.$charges.'</td>';
}




/**
 * This query is suppose to list the number
 * of reconciliation that has been done within one 
 * period.
 */
$bankAccount2= "SELECT
                    a.bankID,
                    a.date
                FROM 
                    `Bank Reconciliation` a 
                group by date";

while($bankRow2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($bankResult2)){
        $bankName=$bankRow2['bankID'];
        $date=$bankRow2['date'];

        echo'
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date </th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        '.$tableHead.'
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$date.'</td>
                        <td>Interest</td>
                        '.$bankInterest.'
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$date.'</td>
                        <td>Charge</td>
                        '.$bankCharges.'
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';
}
```

This still does not work as expected, gives same values for the different reconciliation periods. I guess i am doing something wrong, I would be grateful if someone could help fix it. Thanks

Comment: so what exactly is your question? If you want someone to code it for you, pay a developer ;)

Comment: @cytofu Please I dont need it to be done for me, I just need an idea as to how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: @cytofu, Please kindly look at my question well, i have updated it with what i have tried so far but doesnt seem to work as expected

Comment: Why do you have a GROUP BY clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me

```
reconciliation table
|   reID    |   ABinterest  |   ABcharge    |   CDinterest  |   CDcharges   |       DateRange           |   Year    |
|   1       |   20.00       |     10.00     |       0.00    |       0.00    |   2013/05/01 - 2013/06/31 |   2013    |
|   2       |   0.20        |      0.00     |       50.00   |       0.00    |   2013/07/01 - 2013/09/31 |   2013    |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.bankname
     , LAST_DAY(r.date) date
     , SUM(r.Interest) Interest
     , SUM(r.Charges) Charges 
  FROM reconciliation r 
  JOIN banks b 
    ON b.bankid = r.bankid 
 GROUP 
    BY r.bankid
     , LAST_DAY(r.date)
```

Comment: Please this doesnt work, it gives me the same answer as i did

Comment: Now, the data retrieval (MySQL) works, but the data display (PHP) is the problem

Comment: I have tried using the loop function in php to work around it but to no avail. Can you please also give a try if it will work.

Comment: First, try reversing the order of the GROUP BY - so GROUP BY LAST_DAY(r.date),r.bankid - Does that make it any easier?

Comment: That in any way works on the data retreival part but does not work on the data display part